# can pytest fixture cleanup iff test passes?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a good way to use `pytest` fixtures (especially `pytest-tmpdir`) that only cleanup if the test passed?

I'm testing some terraform, and would want to keep the test directory with state files around in case it fails and I have to go clean up aws resources.

I could use `xtest` style, but would rather not.

Can't figure out how to use yield syntax with send, though seems possible.

Right now I'm

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def tf_ut():
    tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=test_root) # test_root is a session dir that contains the test dirs
    logging.debug('test fixture directory: %s', tmp_dir)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'terraform-provider-http'), tmp_dir)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'terraform-provider-bwafapi'), tmp_dir)
    tf = Terraform(working_dir=tmp_dir)
    tf.init(PROJECT_ROOT)
    return tf


def test_plan_default(tf_ut):
    ret, out, err = tf_ut.init()
    assert ret is 0
    ret, out, err = tf_ut.plan(PROJECT_ROOT, var_file=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'presets/stsdev-dms.tfvars'))
    assert 'Terraform will perform the following actions:' in out
    shutil.rmtree(tf_ut.working_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pytest_runtest_makereport`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_makereport) hook to set the results of test phases in test items, and create a fixture that checks for the status of setup and test execution. If both passed then you can call cleanup logic.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()  
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)

@pytest.yield_fixture
def teardown(request):
    yield
    item = request.node
    if item.rep_setup.passed:
        try:
            call_status = item.rep_call.passed
            if call_status:
                <YOUR CLEAN_UP STEPS>
        except AttributeError:
            <YOUR CLEAN_UP STEPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addfinalizer to do cleanup.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def tf_ut(request, tmpdir):
    tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=test_root) # test_root is a session dir that contains the test dirs
    logging.debug('test fixture directory: %s', tmp_dir)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'terraform-provider-http'), tmp_dir)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'terraform-provider-bwafapi'), tmp_dir)
    tf = Terraform(working_dir=tmp_dir)
    tf.init(PROJECT_ROOT)

    def cleanup(tmpdir):
        if request.node.rep_setup.passed:
           #clean up tmpdir

    request.addfinalizer(cleanup)

    return tf
```

cleanup function will run after each fixture scope (function here).